# fputcsv() putting all data in one row

Tags: php, arrays, fputcsv

I'm working on reading some json, flattening it in to a single array, and then writing it to a csv. I've gotten pretty far but I am currently stuck on the last component. I'm able to pull the data, flatten it, and write it to the csv, but it for some reason it writes all of it in one row, while it should be creating a new line with each new object. I think it's happening because my flattened array is taking multiple objects and combining them in to one, but I cant figure out how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php

$csvArray = array();

function array_flatten($array, $prefix = 'new')
{
if (!is_array($array)) {
    return false;
}
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value, $prefix . '_' . $key));
    } else {
        $result[$prefix . '_' . $key] = $value;
    }
}
return $result;
}

for ($x = 1; $x <= 1; $x++) {

$response = file_get_contents('https://seeclickfix.com/api/v2/issues?page=' . $x . '&per_page=2');

//Decode the JSON and convert it into an associative array.
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($response, true);

$flat = array_flatten($jsonDecoded['issues']);

//Give our CSV file a name.
$csvFileName = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SeeClickFix/all_exports_3/export' . $x . '.csv';

//Open file pointer.
$fp = fopen($csvFileName, 'w');

foreach ($flat as $item) {
    // fputcsv($fp, $item);


    if (is_null($item) || !isset($item) || $item == "Point") {

    } else {

        array_push($csvArray, $item);

    }

  fputcsv($fp, $csvArray);

}


 fclose($fp);



}





?>
```

Comment: What data is in `$jsonDecoded['issues']`? What does `$flat` look like when you `var_dump()` it?

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code - like in the `foreach`, you push on to `$csvArray` but never clear between loops...

Comment: is it truly just one line of it is because the newline is not recognized by your editor when checking the result?